# Mosteller's solution for the long Buffon needle problem

Tags: probability

On page 88 of *Fifty Challenging Problems*, Mosteller gives the following solution for the Buffon needle problem with the length of the needle $l$ longer than the distance between the lines (he uses $1$):

"Let the needle be divided into $n$ pieces of equal length so that all are less than one. If we toss each of these little needles at random, each will have a mean number of crosses obtained from the previous problem. The mean of the sum is the sum of the means, and so their expected number of crosses is $4$(original length)$/\pi$."

For $l=2$ the answer is $8/\pi$ but using the formula obtained from integration (see Wikipedia or Chapter 26 of *Answers from THE BOOK* or [Buffon needle problem , scenario $\ell>d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654306/)) results a complicated formula that does not reduce to $8/\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

I now understand the problem. Mosteller asks for the *expected number of crossings* while the other references solve the original Buffon's needle problem: what is the probability of *at least one crossing*.